# how to get a json file located locally in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

hi i am using angularjs and want to get data from a locally built json file . i tried using $http but no luck. could you please tell some alternate method

```
$http.get("job.json")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.big=response;      
    });
```

this is the method i used and this is my json code

`{
    "days": [{
      "dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
      "date": "2015-08-23",
      "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
    }, {
      "dayname": "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
      "date": "2015-08-24",
      "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
    }, {
      "dayname": "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
      "date": "2015-08-25",
      "hours":"hoursArray(array24)"
    }, {
      "dayname": "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
      "date": "2015-08-26",
      "hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
    }]
}`

Comment: use the correct relative path to the json file. it should solve your issue.

Comment: 1. This is no JSON file. this is Javascript. Please lookup the JSON Syntax! The keys must be wrapped in quotes "" and you can't use functions in a JSON file. - What does `locally built` mean? You built it on the client, browser? Why do you need to use $http to make a remote call if the file is already there somewhere locally?

Comment: sorry for the syntax but i used relative path  its still not working
`$http.get("C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode\test\job.json")
 .success(function(response) {
  $scope.big=response;   
 });
`

Comment: @Michael: i am sorry for the syntax and locally means i have all my files in a folder means javascript and json file and i need to access that data to assign it in  $scope

Comment: **"it does not work"** is not a proper problem description. If you need support you have to deliver a detailed description and some running plunker or jsfiddle examples

Comment: your json formatting is not correct check  the answer below

Comment: First verfiy the format for JSON content. You can verfiy it online using http://jsonlint.com/. Then check the path of JSON file, ideally you should use relative path according to your project. After that check the promise object i.e. success or error. If you are not getting any success, then you'll get an error message.

Comment: actually the problem is  $http.get  is calling the data asynchronously so before the response is coming the next step is performed without receiving data so it is giving error is there some synchronous method to get json data??

Answer (score 1):

you should use factory feature of angular js ,
hee below the complete javascript file. oh by the way i fix your json syntax error. you must quote both value if you use Object type.

```
var mockDataForThisTest = "json=" + encodeURI(JSON.stringify([
{
"dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
"date": "2015-08-23",
"hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
},
{
"dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
"date": "2015-08-23",
"hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
},
{
"dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
"date": "2015-08-23",
"hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
},
{
"dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
"date": "2015-08-23",
"hours": "hoursArray(array24)"
}
]));


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.people = [];

$scope.loadPeople = function() {
    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/echo/json/',
        data: mockDataForThisTest

    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.datas = data;
    });

};

}
```

here is the sample HTML example to show your json

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
<p>    Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
    <td>{{data.dayname}}</td>
    <td>{{data.date}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually i have to get this data from database which i will receive in a json format

Comment: what database you are using ?

Comment: actually the problem is  $http.get  is calling the data asynchronously so before the response is coming the next step is performed without receiving data so it is giving error is there some synchronous method to get json data??

Answer (score -1):

Are you using chrome browser?

If yes the problem should be web security issue in chrome.

Please try to run the chrome using

"**chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**" from your Run command.

And then open your file in that browser. you will be able to get that.

Comment: yes i am using chrome browser will this work in firefox

Comment: In firefox and other browsers this web security will be disabled by default. So you dont have to worry.It will work just fine.

Comment: this is not a code fix, you are just opening chrome browser disabling web security.

Comment: actually the problem is  $http.get  is calling the data asynchronously so before the response is coming the next step is performed without receiving data so it is giving error is there some synchronous method to get json data??

Comment: $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });